# reading / writing RData from C# or F# Deedle package

Tags: r, deedle

Is there any package or function that can help reading and writing R's RData file into C# / F#'s Deedle package?

Comment: I only noticed this question now - next time, feel free to add the "F#" tag to get more visibility for the question!

Answer (score 0):

In the current version, the best way to do this is to use the `new.env`, `ls` and `get` functions from R. The following snippet lists all values in the saved environment:

```
open RDotNet
open RProvider
open RProvider.``base``

// Create new environment and load sample RData file
let env = R.new_env()
let a = R.load(@"C:\Temp\test.rdata", env)

// Use 'ls' to list all values in the environment
for f in R.ls(env).GetValue<string[]>()  do
  // Print the value (using the default conversion)
  R.get("foo", envir=env).Value |> printfn "%A"
```

I put together a simple type provider that lets you do this even more nicely by writing `RData<"Sample.RData">` and generating a type with all the environment objects as members (you can [find a sample here](https://github.com/tpetricek/FSharp.RProvider/blob/rdata.provider/src/RDataProvider/Example.fsx)). To use that you'll need to build the R provider from source in that branch.